# After dualboot installation, screen stopped working

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I had a dualboot working, but needed a fresh install. I went to Windows, wiped the Ubuntu drive. Not the best idea, because I could not boot anymore. So I created a bootable Ubuntu USB and reinstalled Ubuntu.

After the installation process, I was prompted to restart the computer. I did, and removed the USB, and now my screen does not work. What does this mean?

- My pc powers on (power lights, fans moving, ...) but nothing on my screen. No "Packard Bell" logo, nowhere to push F-keys to get in my bios, not even backlight switching on and off. Pure black screen with nothing I can do.

Booting via the USB gives me the same black screen.

So, I guess this could have 2 causes:

- something is messed up with the booting partition. Maybe Ubuntu installed itself on the booting partition instead of the free partition.
- something is messed up with my graphics card, but then again, my backlight should work, I guess.

Anyway, there is no important data on my pc, but I would still like to use it...

Any help is much appreciated because (wait for it) I'm left in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to safely assume you are dual-booting Windows & Ubuntu, in this case using a DVD is recommended.

- Install Windows and Activate it
- When Installing Ubuntu, it will tell you about the detected Windows Partition

  - In That Select Install With Windows or something of that sort.....
  - Leave about 100 - 200 for Ubuntu

Install as Usual and Boot, if there is a problem then it may be hardware.

Thank You!

Comment: How to install windows? Via disk? My bootloader should boot first from USB, but it does not show anything... Will it work via disk?
I don't have any installation disk for windows (pc is 5+ years), I guess I should take it from less legal sources, or is there an alternative?

Comment: Use DVD for Install Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: You may use Torrent for ISO, you get untouched LEGAL ISO's

Comment: But still, if you want to boot and install via disk, you should get past the "branded" page to select: boot via disk. If I don't see anything, I cannot select to boot via disk. But, it's something I'll try!